# Проблема с установкой Virtual Box на Windows Vista x64

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vista

Такая ситуация, нашёл не новый ноут, на нём лицензионная виста x64, сносить жалко и всё что нужно есть для работы, вот только нужна виртуальная машина ещё.
Пробовал ставить Virtual Box какое то время идёт установка, потом прогресс бар откатывается и вылетает ошибка. Можно ли как то установить?
В Интернете полазал, нашёл что могут не работать в висте USB. Я их при инсталяции отключал, даже более того отключил всё кроме ядра - результат точно тот же - ошибка.
Пробовал скачивать более ранние версии, в частности одну из первых 5-ых - результат тот же.
Прочитал про Virtual Box - вижу что ещё с времён XP он существует, думаю что ложен он висту поддерживать, она же всё же была пару лет, неужели Virtual Box под неё не сделали?
Как поставить Virtual Box на Windows Vista?

Comment: И ставить туда хоть 10-ку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что Вы вниз по версиям пошли - тенденция правильная, только видимо не дошли до той которая совместима с Vista. Вам требуется аж 4-ое поколение.
Сейчас зашёл на свой облачный диск на котором у меня всякие драйвера и программы для ноута, оказывается я пользовался под Windows Vista x64 версией VirtualBox-4.1.30-91550-Win
Попробуйте её.

Comment: Зачем обланый диск, если оракл всё ещ ъранит 4-ю ветку? https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

Comment: @donRumata чтобы было под рукой, и точно не зависеть от хранения ораклом

Answer (score 3):

А что такого  драгоценного в лицензии на ОС, которую сами разработчики признали кривой и по выходу Windows 10 дали возможность бесплатно (что для них странно) перейти на Windows 10, если есть OEM-ключ для vista или 8 ?

Рекомендую приобрести лицензию Windows 10 или воспользоваться другими  возможностями.

---

Windows 10 стал весьма дружелюбен для разработки, например такие вещи, как:

- WSL
- windows terminal

в её составе позволили лично мне отказаться от Linux установленного на локальной машине, а также от VirtualBox в котором запускался Linux.

Comment: Забыли пример такой вещи, как лицензия, позволяющая следить за всеми действиями пользователя 

Comment: Можно же через showkey узнать ключ и записать на бумажке.

Comment: Вы не учитываете тот факт что это не новый ноут раз на нём при покупке стояла vista - win 8 на нём уже медленно работает Win 10 ещё медленнее, а в Vista он норм работает, и при том что есть Firefox 52 версии который всё ещё позволяет нормально просматривать сайты - я пока попользуюсь Vista. Для меня это сейчас нормально что такой ноут подвернулся и есть возможность не покупать новый а какое то вермя поработать на нём. С учётом что с Vista он быстро работат, документы поправить и попрограммировать сгодится.

Comment: Субъективно: win10 работает быстрее и стабильнее, чем win8, которая была вместе с ноутом. И, возможно, менее производительно, но значительно стабильнее win7, которая стоит на этом же ноутбуке второй системой.

Comment: @RomanSarin, это какие-то костыли - юзать неподдерижваемую виртуалку на неподдерживаемой ОС. Или хотя бы 7 поставь или на линукс переходи. И чё все бегают с "онаж лицензионная!!!1"? Какие преимущества это даёт, если ты физик? А даже если ты и юрик, то без чеков\договоров на покупку ОС, которые сможешь показать отделу К - все твои "активация пройдена" не сработают.

Comment: @ReinRaus win 10 точно работает медленнее всего, что было до неё. На hdd вообще неюзабельна. И бесплатного обновления с висты до 10 нет, есть только с вин7-8